# Почему не возвращается select и lenp?

Tags: python, функции

```
import string
import random
def num1(select,lenp):  
    i=0
    maxsel=5
    if main(select)==1:
        print("please enter famaly")
        fam=input()
        print("please enter name")
        name=input()
        numbint=int(input())
        numb = []
        while numbint > 0:
            numb.append(numbint % 10)
            numbint = numbint // 10          
        numb=numb[::-1]
        for j in range(main(lenp)):            
            random.shuffle(numb)
            print(name+fam,*numb,sep="")                     
    elif main(select)>=maxsel:
        print("sorry,invalid data :(")

def main():
    print("please enter variation")
    print("1)famaly and name with numbers")
    select=int(input())
    print("please enter pass col")
    lenp=int(input())
    return(select,lenp)
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы в последствии хотите вывести `select, lenp` то и надо задавать функцию чтобы вывести их т.е.:

```
def main():
    select = int(input("please enter variation\n1)famaly and name with numbers\n"))
    lenp = int(input("please enter pass col\n"))
    return select, lenp


print(*main())
```

---

А если в итоге вам нужно чтобы после заполнения `select, lenp` начиналась функция `num1` то на примере вашего кода это будет работать вот так:

```
import random


def num1(select, lenp):

    if select == 1:
        fam = input("please enter famaly\n")
        name = input("please enter name\n")
        numbint = int(input("please enter numbit\n"))
        numb = []
        while numbint > 0:
            numb.append(numbint % 10)
            numbint = numbint // 10
        numb = numb[::-1]
        for j in range(lenp):
            random.shuffle(numb)
            print(name + fam, *numb, sep="")
    elif select > 1:
        print("sorry,invalid data :(")


def main():
    select = int(input("please enter variation\n1)famaly and name with numbers\n"))
    lenp = int(input("please enter pass col\n"))
    return select, lenp


num1(*main())
```